# How to implement C language driver for SPI peripheral

Tags: c, spi, interrupts

I have been implementing device driver for the SPI peripheral of the MCU in C language. I would like to exploit interrupt mechanism for reception and also for transmission.

As far as the reception part I think that I can implement this via exposing the function SpiRegisterCallback into the SPI driver interface. This function enables the client register its function which will be invoked as soon as data byte is received (reception buffer full interrupt is invoked).

As far as the transmission part I would like to use some SpiTransmit function which will receive pointer to the data bytes to be transmitted and number of bytes to be transmitted. As far as implementation I am going to define some internal callback function of the SPI driver. This internall callback will be registered for transmission buffer empty interrupt. In this callback function the passed data bytes will be gradually placed into the transmission buffer. I am not sure whether this approach is appropriate. Can anybody give me an advice how to implement SPI peripheral driver which exploits interrupts for data transmission? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It is difficult to critique your design without some background on what problem you are attempting to solve. Can you elaborate on the goal in using interrupts here? That is improved throughput, or latency, asynchronous operation, and so on.

Comment: Although this particular question is on-topic here, please don't cross post across multiple sites. Your question already got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402161/how-to-exploit-interrupts-for-data-transfer-over-spi-peripheral) on SO. That way we avoid answering already answered questions. Voting to close.

Comment: Sounds like how MCU manufacturers do their HAL drivers these days. For simple projects that's overly complex though. If the transmit and receive callbacks are internal they don't need to be callbacks, the interrupt handler can just handle storing/reading data from buffers.

Comment: Such callbacks aren't really very useful to an application, if you are doing something for your own use you might as well just implement software buffering to deal in whole messages.  Actual application needs are pretty much always ultimately either blocking or polled.   And if you are trying to write something of general application, don't - you need more experience first to be able to create designs which are generally useful, even most professionally created generic I/O libraries end up painful to actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPI protocol ties reading to writing. For each transmitted byte, a byte is received. Thus transmission and reception aren't independent and your SPI design should reflect that.

Therefore, you don't want a callback for each received byte as the link to the transmission is lost. Furthermore, it's far too slow to achieve data rates of 10 MHz or more.

In my experience, two approaches work:

**Blocking byte operations**

An Arduino like `spi_transfer_byte()` function: it sends a byte and returns the byte received at the same time. The function blocks until the byte has been received. Additionally, there are functions to start and end the SPI transaction (for the chip select signal). This pattern is easy to use, easy to implement, small in code size and often good enough.

**Asynchronous SPI transactions**

A higher-level API to execute entire SPI transactions. An array of bytes can be sent (similar to the way you have proposed). The function returns immediately as the transmission happens asynchronously. When the transmission has completed, a callback is called providing the received bytes (the same number as transmitted). For maximum performance, it should be possible to queue several SPI transactions. The callback should contain a reference to the submitted transaction.

This approach is more complex and usually requires DMA support for implementation (an interrupt for each byte is usually too slow). It can achieve higher throughput, is efficient for large SPI transactions (e.g. for LCD displays), does not block the rest of the code and is also suitable for RTOS.